# How to autowire Application context in a ScheduledFutures runnable task

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, runnable, applicationcontext

I am trying to create a module for running report tasks based on configuration. The thought is to pass report configuration to a single task for defining each report specifics. Report configuration contains data information and class names that will be invoked to do the separate tasks. For this I have a Scheduling Service for dynamically configuring on startup my scheduled tasks. Task (runnable impl) is ReportExecutor.

```
@Service
public class ReportSchedulingService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReportSchedulingService.class);

    @Autowired
    private ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler;

    @Autowired
    private ReportList reportList;

    private static Map<String, ScheduledFuture<?>> jobsMap = new HashMap<String, ScheduledFuture<?>>();

    public void scheduleAllReports() {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Report> reportEntry : reportList.getReports().entrySet()) {
            String reportName = reportEntry.getKey();
            Report report = reportEntry.getValue();
            String jobId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            logger.info(String.format("Scheduling report [%s] with job id: [%s] and cron expression: [%s]",
                reportName, jobId, report.getCron()));
            ReportExecutor execution = new ReportExecutor();
            report.setId(jobId);
            report.setName(reportName);
            execution.setTaskDefinition(report);
            ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledTask = taskScheduler.schedule(execution,
                new CronTrigger(report.getCron(), TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault().getID())));
            getJobMap().put(reportName + "_" + jobId, scheduledTask);
        }
    }

    private synchronized Map<String, ScheduledFuture<?>> getJobMap() {
        if (jobsMap == null) {
            jobsMap = new HashMap<String, ScheduledFuture<?>>();
        }
        return jobsMap;
    }

    public void removeScheduledTask(String jobId) {
        ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledTask = getJobMap().get(jobId);
        if (scheduledTask != null) {
            scheduledTask.cancel(true);
            getJobMap().put(jobId, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Report Executor is:

```
@Component
public class ReportExecutor implements Runnable {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    private Report reportDefinition;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
        System.out.println(reportDefinition);
        IReportGenerator generator = appContext.getBean(
            reportDefinition.getExecute(),
            IReportGenerator.class);
        JSONArray reportData = generator.generate(reportDefinition);

        IReportNotifier notifier =
            appContext.getBean(reportDefinition.getNotification().getExecute(), IReportNotifier.class);
        notifier.send(reportDefinition, reportData);

    }
    public Report getTaskDefinition() {
        return reportDefinition;
    }
    public void setTaskDefinition(Report reportDefinition) {
        this.reportDefinition = reportDefinition;
    }
}
```

But I have also tried with:

```
@Component
public class ReportExecutor implements Runnable, ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    private Report reportDefinition;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
        System.out.println(reportDefinition);
        IReportGenerator generator = appContext.getBean(
            reportDefinition.getExecute(),
            IReportGenerator.class);
        JSONArray reportData = generator.generate(reportDefinition);

        IReportNotifier notifier =
            appContext.getBean(reportDefinition.getNotification().getExecute(), IReportNotifier.class);
        notifier.send(reportDefinition, reportData);

    }

    public Report getTaskDefinition() {
        return reportDefinition;
    }

    public void setTaskDefinition(Report reportDefinition) {
        this.reportDefinition = reportDefinition;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.appContext = applicationContext;
    }

}
```

Seems that I cannot get the application context here and end up to a NPE at:

```
        IReportGenerator generator = appContext.getBean(
```

The stackTrace is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at ote.itarc.report.ReportExecutor.run(ReportExecutor.java:27) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93) [spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836) [?:?]
```

ReportList object comes from yaml properties:

```
reportlist:
  reports:
    missinginfra:
      desc: "This report provides ..."
      execute: QueryReportGenerator
      query: SELECT * FROM DUAL
      cron: "0 0/2 * 1/1 * ?"
      notification:
        execute: EmailCsvReportNotifier
        templateid: 0
```

With the following definition

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "reportlist")
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class ReportList {

    private Map<String, Report> reports;

    public Map<String, Report> getReports() {
        return reports;
    }

    public void setReports(Map<String, Report> reports) {
        this.reports = reports;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ReportList [reports=" + reports + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't create an instance with `new`. Manage it through spring and get an instance through the context. Don't use the run method to later inject dependencies, just let spring do all that, you are basically trying to make things overly complex with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `ReportExecutor` a Spring managed bean and make it prototype scoped. Next in your `ReportSchedulingService` use the `ApplicationContext` to get an instance (and let Spring do the wiring) and schedule it.

```java
@Service
public class ReportSchedulingService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReportSchedulingService.class);

    private final Map<String, ScheduledFuture<?>> jobsMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, ScheduledFuture<?>>();

    private final TaskScheduler taskScheduler;
    private final ReportList reportList;
    private final ApplicationContext ctx;

    public ReportSchedulingService(ReportList reportList, TaskScheduler taskScheduler, ApplicationContext ctx) {
        this.reportList=reportList;
        this.taskScheduler=taskScheduler;
        this.ctx=ctx;
    }

    public void scheduleAllReports() {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Report> reportEntry : reportList.getReports().entrySet()) {
            String reportName = reportEntry.getKey();
            Report report = reportEntry.getValue();
            String jobId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            logger.info(String.format("Scheduling report [%s] with job id: [%s] and cron expression: [%s]",
                reportName, jobId, report.getCron()));
            ReportExecutor execution = ctx.getBean(ReportExecutor.class);
            report.setId(jobId);
            report.setName(reportName);
            execution.setTaskDefinition(report);
            ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledTask = taskScheduler.schedule(execution,
                new CronTrigger(report.getCron(), TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault().getID())));
            this.jobsMap.put(reportName + "_" + jobId, scheduledTask);
        }
    }

    public void removeScheduledTask(String jobId) {
        ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledTask = this.jobsMap.get(jobId);
        if (scheduledTask != null) {
            scheduledTask.cancel(true);
            getJobMap().put(jobId, null);
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I took the liberty to improve your code a little as well, using constructor injection and using a `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of `syncronized`.

```java
@Component
@Scope(scopeName=SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class ReportExecutor implements Runnable {

    private final ApplicationContext appContext;
    private Report reportDefinition;

    public ReportExecutor(ApplicationContext ctx) {
      this.appContext=ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        IReportGenerator generator = appContext.getBean(
            reportDefinition.getExecute(),
            IReportGenerator.class);
        JSONArray reportData = generator.generate(reportDefinition);

        IReportNotifier notifier =
            appContext.getBean(reportDefinition.getNotification().getExecute(), IReportNotifier.class);
        notifier.send(reportDefinition, reportData);

    }

    public void setTaskDefinition(Report reportDefinition) {
        this.reportDefinition = reportDefinition;
    }
}
```

The scoped proxy will create a new instance for each call to `getBean`. So you get a fresh, clean instance for each execution you want to schedule.

Comment: Thank you! I already saw that new caused the problem but the additional input is very helpful!!

Comment: Seems that proxyMode=TARGET_CLASS makes the assignment of the reportDefinition unusuable and throws a NPE at: reportDefinition.getExecute().
If I don't issue a proxymode then all works as expected.

Comment: Correct, basically when using `TARGET_CLASS` each method invocation on the target will lead to a new instance. I figured that out right after the answer, but forgot to edit.